Получение данных по GPIO На Esp8266
У меня есть сервопривод со своим внутренним микроконтроллером AX-12A от Dynamixel и ESP8266, которая управляет вшитым в сервак микроконтроллером. И у меня возникает вопрос, так-как рабочее напряжение AX-12A составляет 12В, а esp8266 3.3В. Если я попробую получить данные с AX-12A не сгорит ли моя ESP8266?

Используй конверторы уровней сигнала. Простенькие на транзисторах для схем управления 5в или на оптопарах для силовых аппаратов.
Для вашего случая типовая схема

Тут ещё 1wire.
Слева подтяжку поменяй на 3.3 и должно сработать. Но лучше используй дополнительно преобразователь уровней (level shifter).
